# Laravel Retrieving data from two tables with same columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I hope this is not duplicated.

I have two tables in **first table (users)** there is column **(uid and tokenn)** the ids of registered users.
When a ***guest*** from outside website sends a message to **(uid)**, a function posts the message to **(posts table)** and column **(uid)** turns to **(to_id)** in posts table.

I want to get the **(tokeen)** of the **(to_id)** which is **(uid)** in **users table** in order to let Firebase push notification to that token.

users table:

| id | uid | name | email | password | tokenn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 6 | o | o | o | 12313 |

Posts table:

| id | pid | from_id | to_id | feedback |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 |  |  | 6 | 12313 |

**My postsController.php**

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\post;
use Auth;
use Lang;

class postsController extends Controller
{
    public function send_feedback(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request,[
            'feedback_image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:3072',
            'feedback_content' => 'required|max:500'
        ]);
        $pid = rand(9,999999999)+time();
        if (Auth::user()) {
            $from_id = Auth::user()->uid;
        }elseif (Auth::guest()) {
            $from_id = 0;
        }
        $to_id = $request['hidden2'];
        $feedback = $request['feedback_content'];
        $image = $request->file('feedback_image');
        $time = $request['hidden'];
        if ($request->hasFile('feedback_image')) {
            $img_ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $img_name = rand(9,9999999)+time()+rand(0,55555).".".$img_ext;
            $img_new = $image->storeAs("fbImgs",$img_name);
        }else{
            $img_name = "";
        }
        $post = new post();
        $post->pid = $pid;
        $post->from_id = $from_id;
        $post->to_id = $to_id;
        $post->feedback = $feedback;
        $post->image = $img_name;
        $post->time = $time;
        $post->save();
        
        //
        
        
        
        define('API_ACCESS_KEY','xxx');
 $fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$token = User::where('uid', $to_id)->first()->tokenn;







    $notification = [
            'title' =>'xxx',
            'body' => 'xxx',
            'icon' =>'myIcon', 
            'sound' => 'mySound'
        ];
        $extraNotificationData = ["message" => $notification,"moredata" =>'dd'];

        $fcmNotification = [
            //'registration_ids' => $tokenList, //multple token array
            'to'        => $token, //single token
            'notification' => $notification,
            'data' => $extraNotificationData
        ];

        $headers = [
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ];


        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        
        
        
        
        //
        
    
        return redirect()->back()->with('feedback_sent',Lang::get('trans.fb_sent'));
    }
    public function postPrivacy(Request $request){
        $pid_var = $request['pid'];
        $pid_ex = explode("_", $pid_var);
        $pid = @$pid_ex[1];
        if ($request['status'] == "true") {
            $updatePrivacy = post::where('pid',$pid)->update(['privacy' => 1]);
        }else{
            $updatePrivacy = post::where('pid',$pid)->update(['privacy' => 0]);
        }
        return $pid;
    }
    public function deletePost(Request $request){
        $checkID = post::where('pid',$request['pid'])->get()->count();
        if ($checkID > 0) {
            $allowed = post::where('pid',$request['pid'])->get();
            foreach ($allowed as $getAllowed) {
                $to_id = $getAllowed->to_id;
                $from_id = $getAllowed->from_id;
            }
            if ($to_id == Auth::user()->uid || $from_id == Auth::user()->uid) {
                $deleteFB = post::where('pid',$request['pid'])->delete();
                return "done";
            }else{
                return Lang::get('trans.delPost_notAllowed');
            }
        }else{
            return Lang::get('trans.err_somethingWrong');
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to retrieving the token of the recipient of the message as follows:

```html
$token=Auth::user()->tokenn; //but it returns the logged in and the sender user's token which is wrong.
```

```html
$token = User::find($to_id)->tokenn;
$token = User::where('uid', $to_id)->first()->tokenn;

//these both are not working too
```

I need to Retrieving the token of the recipient When A GUEST sends a message to any.

Here's my website : https://www.secreta.me/omar

Hope I'm clear.

Comment: what's the result of ```$token = User::where('uid', $to_id)->first()->tokenn;``` ?

Comment: @alirezadp10 it should returns the value in tokenn column of the recipient user

Comment: ok. tell me what the result of this line? because this line must be return what you want.

Comment: @alirezadp10, ah sorry.

Result: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\User' not found"

Comment: kidding me? where is the User.php and what is its namespace?

Comment: Brother. I'm just new to laravel. Can you please help me with the last step of my small project.
Can you explain User.php content and it's namespace. My appreciation to you and respect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must Create User.php in your models directory

this class by default created when you install laravel, but if you delete it unintentionally you can create it by:

```
php artisan make:model User
```

and in your Controller you must use this model instead of `App\Http\Controllers\User`.

so In other words you must use
`App\User` in laravel 7 and below or use `App\Models\User` in laravel 8 in your Controller like below.

```
use App\User; // if your laravel version is 7 or below

use App\Models\User; // if your laravel version is 8 or higher
```

Comment: This was very helpful brother. Thank you very much. I have been messing this for so long.
Much appreacation brother.

use App\User; wasn't added in postcontroller :D